# SSIS problem loading data from csv file to SQL Server table

Tags: ssis

I have a simple SSIS package that loads from csv (comma delimited) file to the table.  It was working just fine until now, and the issue is that the new file has a few extra fields in the last records:
20,30,40.5,50
15,20,25.5,30
10,20,30.5,40,**50.5**
The package is concatenating 50.5 in the last row with 40 and gives a formatting error.  If I delete 50.5, the package runs without issues.  Is there a way to set it up so it would ignore extra columns?

Comment: are the first 4 columns always numbers?

Comment: It's just an example, so no, can be anything.

Comment: well my answer still works unless you have commas inside your fields. You just have to cast the strings to the correct data types.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file in as a single column of text.

Push that into a script transformation and name your 4 output columns...

```
string s = Row.[singlestring];
```

Use split...

```
string[] pieces = s.Split(',');
```

Output [0-3]...

```
Row.[Col1] = decimal.Parse(pieces[0]);
Row.[Col2] = decimal.Parse(pieces[1]);
Row.[Col3] = decimal.Parse(pieces[2]);
Row.[Col4] = decimal.Parse(pieces[3]);
```

And just ignore the remaining pieces.

Comment: use decimal.Parse() instead. I see your numbers are not ints

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to create a sample CSV file with 5 columns and use it to map the source.
Once you mapped the five columns, specify only the first four columns to be considered in your data flow and then use your original file. This will be a workaround to ignore your extra column.

You can also follow [these steps](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b241accf-eed5-4a4e-a8f7-296b44ddbe81/ssis-how-to-ignore-extra-columns-in-flat-file-load?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: The issue here is that the file is not under my control, it can have any number of columns in the future.