# Extract columns from Flatfiles in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have multiple flat files, each containing a different number of columns with different names. What they all have in common is the first two columns (`ID`, `name`)—but after that, some have seven additional columns, others have fifteen, etc.

I need to get the first two columns into a database. Usually that would not be hard: Just use the Flat File Connection Manager, map correctly, and deactivate the columns I don't need.

Now this whole operation is in a loop and is supposed to work for *all* of the Flat Files in my folder. Is there any way I can do this without needing to create a Connection Manager for *every* file that has a different number of columns?

Comment: I have exactly this process in place but not using SSIS, using t-sql and bulkload.

Comment: You can load the entire data row (as a single column) into a staging table in SQL for each file (maybe append the file name or some identifier as well), then in SQL side parse out only the first 2 columns that you need.

Comment: You might want to try to create a C# Source Component - there you can perform the column splitting and push only the columns required into the output... so you basically loop over all files in a folder and it doesn't mater if the file has 2 or 200 columns... However, you will have to handle the case that a file only includes one single column as well.

Comment: @Tyron78 that sounds helpful - you got any links/examples how the splitting itself is done/displayed within the skript? I'm pretty much a newbie and I got no clue reg. C#

Comment: @vincevang there are several resources on the web regarding this. You might want to check the following two:
https://www.sqlshack.com/using-the-ssis-script-component-as-a-data-source/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6149/import-text-and-csv-files-into-sql-server-database-with-ssis-script-task/

Comment: My answer here solves this same issue using c# script task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989660/ssis-problem-loading-data-from-csv-file-to-sql-server-table/69003281#69003281